# JMeter authentication error : 401

Tags: jmeter

Currently I am having problem to login my application using Jmeter scripts for SSO login.Shows unauthorized but all my credentials that I provided to login into application are okay.

It was working earlier.

I have already implemented each and everything that require to run Jmeter to my application earlier.

Currently I am stuck at this point.If anyone has idea? If so it would be so nice to have that idea/help.

[image: Images for Jmeter Setup and Error]

Comment: Password might have expired or changed. Are you able to login manually?

Answer (score 1):

check if it is NTLM authentication then you need to provide Mechanism as "Basic Digest" and if any domain then mention in Realm as "{domainname}\"

Answer (score 0):

Most probably this is due to irrelevant configuration of the [HTTP Authorization Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager)

Looking into [WWW-Authenticate Negotiate](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4559), it seems application you are testing is using [NTLM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NT_LAN_Manager) or [Kerberos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_(protocol)) authentication so you need to properly configure JMeter in order to be able to bypass it.

See [Windows Authentication with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-apache-jmeter) article for more detailed explanation and example configurations for NTLM and Kerberos.